# How do i get a value buried in a OrderedDict

Tags: python

I have a variable "case" that calls OrderedDict:

```
OrderedDict([('totalSize', 1),
         ('done', True),
         ('records',
          [OrderedDict([('attributes',
                         OrderedDict([('type', 'Case'),
                                      ('url',
                                       '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Case/5003700000ReKcJAAV')])),
                        ('Id', '5003700000ReKcJAAV')])])])
```

I want a variable 'Id' to return '5003700000ReKcJAAV'. Is there a way to do that?

I'm using Python 3.6.5

Comment: It sounds like you need to implement a tree traversal of your nested data structure.

Comment: `print(d['records'][0]['Id'])` - you need to loop through `d['records']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks ugly but, works.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
z = OrderedDict([('totalSize', 1),
         ('done', True),
         ('records',
          [OrderedDict([('attributes',
                         OrderedDict([('type', 'Case'),
                                      ('url',
                                       '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Case/5003700000ReKcJAAV')])),
                        ('Id', '5003700000ReKcJAAV')])])])
print(z.get('records')[0].get('Id'))
```

Output:

```
5003700000ReKcJAAV
```

Comment: Strange, I've got:   File "<ipython-input-32-603aa2b5b424>", line 9
    print z.get('records')[0].get('Id')
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: my Python 3.6.5

Comment: @RomanKulakov, now please check. Done changes for Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the below code.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json

l = [('totalSize', 1),
         ('done', True),
         ('records',
          [OrderedDict([('attributes',
                         OrderedDict([('type', 'Case'),
                                      ('url',
                                       '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Case/5003700000ReKcJAAV')])),
                        ('Id', '5003700000ReKcJAAV')])])]
ordDict = OrderedDict(l)

print json.dumps(ordDict, indent=4)
"""
{
    "totalSize": 1,
    "done": true,
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Case",
                "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Case/5003700000ReKcJAAV"
            },
            "Id": "5003700000ReKcJAAV"
        }
    ]
}
"""

print ordDict['records'][0]['Id'] # 5003700000ReKcJAAV
```

Answer (score 0):

It was easier, then i was expecting. I just needed to:

```
Id = case['records'][0]['Id']
```

Comment: This is fine. However, will throw error if key not found. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11041421/5014656